# Multi row data parsing through JSON in Android

Tags: android, json

can anyone give me some help that how can i parse multi row data that is return from server through web api call.kindly provide a piece of code that show idea that how to show multi row data of json parsing in android. Thanks in Advance

i run this query in api file and retun it to my app
select * from experience;

above query get multi records of a user if he has more then one experience

Comment: What about a JSON example from your api call?

Comment: yeah i would be better

Answer (score 1):

say your json is like this

```
 {"person":[{"name":"Ajit",
             "Age": 23},
            {"name":"Aparna",
             "Age":22}]}
```

then your parsing class will be

```
class Parser{
    @SerializedName("person")
    private ArrayList<Person> person;
}

class Person{
    @SerializedName("name")
     private String name;
    @serializedName("Age")
     private int age;
}
```

I am using google's gson to parse json , just use getter to get the data

Hope this helps :)

Comment: one thing i want to ask do i use loop to get multiple rows like loop to get both ajit and aparna records at same time and view them on listview ?

Comment: bro i'm new to this can i have a example of code ? please

Comment: http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/binding-android-listview-with-custom-objects-using-arrayadapter   this link should help... just pass the people list as shown in example

Comment: is there any way to send queries from android app to web api? instead of wriitng query in api files